# where is the error in the sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, global-variables

i have a PHP code that includes SQL query where the user select from dropdown list and based on its selection the SQL query retrieve the data.

the problem is that when  i tried to compare the selected data with the existing value in the database  the query doesn't work. i tried to display the value of the variable before and after the query and its the same as the user selection. so i am sure that the problem is inside the **SQL QUERY**  where i compare `i.siteNAME = '".$site_name."'`

how to fix this i have been stuck with this code for 5 days and still counting.

this is a part of the  code :

```
    <?php
            /*
            Template Name: search info
            */

            get_header();
            ?>

            <?php
            // code for submit button action
            global $wpdb, $site_name;
        //variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)



        if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
        {


           if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
              { 

               $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
              }
              else { $site_name=""; }

            if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
             {
              $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 
             } 
             else { $owner_name=""; }

             if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
             {
              $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];
             } 
             else { $company_name=""; }

            if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
            { 
             $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 
            }
            else { $Subcontractor_name="";}

        var_dump($site_name);

        $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("
    select i.siteID
         , i.siteNAME
         , i.equipmentTYPE
         , c.latitude
         , c.longitude
         , c.height 
         , o.ownerNAME
         , o.ownerCONTACT
         , x.companyNAME
         , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
         , y.subcontractorNAME
         , y.subcontractorCONTACT
      from site_info i
      LEFT  
      JOIN owner_info o
        on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
      LEFT  
      JOIN company_info x
        on i.companyID = x.companyID
      LEFT 
      JOIN subcontractor_info y
        on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
        LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` c
        on i.siteID=c.siteID 
        where 
        i.siteNAME = '".$site_name."'
        AND 
        o.ownerNAME = '".$owner_name." '
        AND 
        x.companyNAME = '".$company_name."'
        ");
        var_dump($_POST['site_name']);
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
             echo $site_name;
            echo $owner_name;
            echo $company_name;
           echo $Subcontractor_name;


    foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
                 echo "query is working";
        echo "<table width='30%' ";
    echo     "<tr>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
    echo     "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
        } 
     ?>
<table width="30%" >
        <tr>
           <td>Site Name</td>
           <td>Owner Name</td>
           <td>Company Name</td>
           <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
           <td>Site ID</td>
           <td>Equipment Type</td>
           <td> Lattitude</td>
           <td>Longitude </td>
           <td> Height</td>
           <td> Owner Contact</td>
           <td> Sub Contact</td>
           <td> Sub company Name</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
  <?php }
?>  
<!--  the below part  of code work as it should   --!>
    <!--create  dropdown list site names-->

    <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Name</td>
               <td>Owner Name</td>
               <td>Company Name</td>
               <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

                 <?php


                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
                       $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>

                <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
                <?php
                 global $owner_name;
                      $query_owner_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT ownerNAME  from owner_info");
                      foreach($query_owner_name as $owner_name)
                      {
                         $owner_name = (array)$owner_name;
                         echo "<option value = '{".$owner_name ['ownerNAME']."}'>".  $owner_name['ownerNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                  ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
                <?php 
                global $Company_name;
                     $query_Company_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT companyNAME  from company_info");
                     foreach($query_Company_name as $Company_name)
                     {
                       $Company_name = (array)$Company_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$Company_name ['companyNAME']."}'>".  $Company_name['companyNAME']."</option>";
                     }  
                 ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Subcontractor names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Subcontractor_name"  name ="Subcontractor_name">
                <?php 
                global $Subcontractor_name;
                    $query_Subcontractor_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT subcontractorNAME  from subcontractor_info");
                     foreach($query_Subcontractor_name as $Subcontractor_name)
                     {
                       $Subcontractor_name = (array)$Subcontractor_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$Subcontractor_name ['subcontractorNAME']."}'>".  $Subcontractor_name['subcontractorNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                   ?>
                </select></td>
            <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <input type ="submit" name="query_submit" value ="Search" />

        </td>
       </tr>

        </table>
    </form>


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: so, how do we know if the (unknown) form isn't at fault (also) ?

Comment: Before solving your problem, you should take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn something about SQL injection. The way your code is written is really unsafe and your database could be hacked in a few seconds.

Comment: did you check for errors via error reporting and the query?

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerability, you need to rewrite this using $wpdb->prepare

Comment: btw, `echo "<table width='30%' ";` you never closed off that table with `>` so that'll break something. and you're creating a table for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no everything is closed this is a part of the code
 i will edit my question and add the rest of the code  to insure that the form is correct

Comment: @AlexK. I KNOW about the sql injection vulnerability  but meanwhile i need to fix my problem then i will fine-tunning  the code in  a way to prevent sql injection

Comment: @Twinfriends  I KNOW about the sql injection vulnerability but meanwhile i need to fix my problem then i will fine-tunning the code in a way to prevent sql injection

Comment: Why would you go out of your way to fix insecure db-calls if you're going to rebuild them to be secure anyway? The db-calls will look different so why not just do it correctly from the start? Otherwise you're might just end up back here again when the refactoring doesn't work.

Comment: So what does the query return ? Wrong results or none at all ? Could you try replacing `$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results` by `echo` and then execute it directly in your PHPMyAdmin ?

Comment: @roberto06 you i replace **$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results** statement by **echo**  when i execute the query giving specified values from the database everything works

Comment: As @Fred-ii- pointed out, you're not closing your opening table tag: `echo "<table width='30%' ";`. <-- missing the last `>`. Don't think that's because of you posted partial code.

Comment: Well, if the echoed statement returns the expected results when executed in your database, the problem **is definitely not the SQL string**.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson OP wrote [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418219/where-is-the-error-in-the-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment71981902_42418219) - we're still waiting. Plus, I also asked about the form, error reporting check and on the query; got back "nada".

Comment: @roberto06 i am saying that the error is in the variable that is been compared inside the **SQL**   this variable **$site_name**

Comment: I'm just wondering if we're going to have to wait "5 days" also to get the real code and possible (real) errors, if any. This question is getting to receive too many comments.

Comment: And I'm saying it isn't. Once again, if the statement return the correct results when copied in your database, that means it is well constructed, hence the problem isn't there, nor is it in the variables that are concatenated in the statement.

Comment: `$owner_name = (array)$owner_name;`? Ok, again.... error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and error handling on the query, var_dump, viewing html source and tell us what gives. I tried.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i already added the rest of the code hoping that anyone will know how to fix it or at least find the error

Comment: *@Fred-ii- i already added the rest of the code hoping that anyone will know how to fix it or at least find the error* hehe!! so knw you want use to debug your messy code? the reason ppl say use prepared statements, it because its so easy to debug queries

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i didn't convert the variable to array it  display the below warning:

    Array to string conversion in

Comment: anw guys thank you  for your answers but if i knew  that you will make funny of my question i would never asked

Comment: Sorry @Nabil, it's not about making fun of you or your question. But your question is not really good for SO (too broad), and advised you received here you rejected. Good luck with this nonetheless.

Comment: @yivi   i did not reject any advise  but i was hoping that i fix this problem then i will fix the rest  but you guys didn't answer my question all you did is criticize me for this question

Comment: Again, your question, as it stands, is not a [good](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question, so it isn't easy to help you. You need to reduce your problem to a [MCVE], specify what problems you find with your code ("it doesn't work" is **not enough**). Very likely, while doing this you'll fix your problem yourself! Or if not, you'll end up with something that will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: And if you pay heed to people telling you to use prepared statements and bound parameters, your problem is likely to be solved anyway. Still, is true that people around here could (should?) be nicer, even if your question is not good as it stands, or you are not making particularly easy to help you. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

i solved my question there wasn't any error in the query, the problem was in the iteration process inside the **foreach** loop.

i was fetching the query as **array** that was the error it must be fetched as **object**
the line that i changed was :

```
 echo "<option value = '{".$owner_name ['ownerNAME']."}'>".  $owner_name['ownerNAME']."</option>";
```

it becomes

```
echo "<option value = '".$owner_name->ownerNAME."'>".  $owner_name->ownerNAME."</option>";
```